# Unable to set approval nor transfer ownership in ERC721 smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft, erc721

Can someone explain to me how I can set approval for ERC721 contract ?

1- At first, the token once minted belongs to the marketplace
2- with buy, I need to transfer ownership of the token to the caller

I keep getting these errors

X Fail with error 'ERC721: approve caller is not token owner nor approved for all'
x Fail with error 'ERC721: approve to caller'

This is my smart contract : the `mint`  `buy` function
//The first time a token is created, it is listed here
function createToken(string memory tokenURI, string memory name,  uint256 price) public payable returns (uint) {
uint256 currentTokenId = _tokenIds.current();

```
    //Mint the NFT with tokenId newTokenId to the address who called createToken
    _safeMint(msg.sender, currentTokenId);

    //Map the tokenId to the tokenURI (which is an IPFS URL with the NFT metadata)
    _setTokenURI(currentTokenId, tokenURI);

    //Helper function to update Global variables and emit an event
    _create(currentTokenId, tokenURI, name, listPrice);

    setApprovalForAll(address(this), true);

    //Increment the tokenId counter, which is keeping track of the number of minted NFTs
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current(); 
    return newTokenId;
}

function _create(uint256 tokenId, string memory tokenURI, string memory name,  uint256 price) private {
    //Make sure the sender sent enough ETH to pay for listing
    require(msg.value == listPrice, "Hopefully sending the correct price");
    
    //Just sanity check
    require(price > 0, "Make sure the price isn't negative");

    //Update the mapping of tokenId's to Token details, useful for retrieval functions
    idToToken[tokenId] = Token(
        tokenId,
        tokenURI,
        name,
        payable(address(this)),
        price,
        true
    );

    _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
    //Emit the event for successful transfer. The frontend parses this message and updates the end user
    emit TokenListedSuccess(
        tokenId,
        address(this),
        price,
        true
    );
}
function buyNFT(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "You need to send some ether");
        require(msg.value == idToToken[tokenId].price, "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");

        approve(msg.sender, tokenId);
        setApprovalForAll(msg.sender, true);

        transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender,tokenId);
       //  safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
        payable(idToToken[tokenId].owner).transfer(msg.value);

        //update the details of the token
        idToToken[tokenId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
        idToToken[tokenId].isForSale = false;
        _itemsSold.increment();
   
        //Transfer the proceeds from the sale to the seller of the NFT
        payable(address(this)).transfer(msg.value);

        // emit Event
    }
```

this is my client app :

```
const buyToken = (...args) => {
            const [tokenId] = args
            return new Promise(async resolve => {
               try {
                    let transaction = await contract.buyNFT(tokenId, { 
                        gasLimit: 5500000, 
                        value: price.toString()
                    });
                    await transaction.wait();
                    resolve()
               } catch (e) {
                  console.error(e)
               }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with

```
transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender,tokenId);
```

You are transferring from the contract address to the `msg.sender` but it should be from the `nft owner` or `token id owner`.

> The approve() function grants a third party the ability to transfer a
> single token id. setApprovalForAll() will grant a third party the
> ability to transfer all of the tokens you own for a given collection.

When we mint the token we call `setApprovalForAll()` to authorize the marketplace to transfer our token. This is the `trasferFrom`

```
function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public virtual override {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");

        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

Before transferring it is checking if the `msg.sender` is already authorized for this transaction or from address is the "owner" of token. To solve the issue get the owner of the `tokenId`. Since you are passing the "tokenId`to the`buyNFT`

```
  address owner=ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
  transferFrom(owner, msg.sender,tokenId);
```